# How to change the background of all activities with preferenceChange?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, sharedpreferences, android-preferences

I have a checkbox in my android settings activity . I want to change the background color of all activities of my app with the change in preferenceCheckBox value .

my code:

**SettingsFragment.java**

```java
public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {
    private SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener preferenceChangeListener;
    @Override
    public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle bundle, String s) {
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preference);

        preferenceChangeListener = new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
                if( key.equals("pref_light")){
                    Preference p = findPreference(key);
                    //i don't know how to change the background with the provided change !
                }
            }
        };

    }
```

**MY QUESTION**
i want to learn how to change the background of all activities with the preference change i have listened . suppose i only have one mainactivity and one settings activity .

Answer (score 0):

Take note that, by default, a `PreferenceFragmentCompat` saves the values in an object called `SharedPreferences` which is accessible anywhere in you application. Details here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings

Thus, you can do this anywhere in your application:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences =
    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
boolean isChecked = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(“pref_light”, "");
```

Comment: this works fine if i go back and reload the activity . but how do i make the background change as soon as i check or uncheck the checkbox

Comment: put a checker on every activity's `onStart` and see for "pref_light" value. basically, you are interested if the value changed to avoid unnecessary redraws.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access all views in your app from one fragment. However you can override onResume() method in your activities. Inside it you can check preferences and set desired background.

```
@Override  
protected void onResume() {  
    super.onResume();  
    SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("MyPref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    Boolean backgroundFlag = pref.getBoolean("pref_light", true);
    View rootView = findViewById(R.id.your_view_id);
    if (backgroundFlag) {
        rootView.setBackground(someColor);
    } else {
        rootView.setBackground(someOtherColor);
    }
}
```

Comment: i tried this way but it only sets the value to true if i write :

```java
Boolean backgroundFlag = pref.getBoolean("pref_light", true);
```

and sets to false if i write 

```java
Boolean backgroundFlag = pref.getBoolean("pref_light", false);
```

Comment: You have to save value of boolean to preferences first inside Fragment.
https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences#java

Answer (score 0):

Save your preference from fragment like,

```
 SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("Pref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
 prefs.edit().putBoolean("pref_light",true).apply();
```

The next code is for applying change of background color for all the activities.
You can create a BaseActivity and onResume of BaseActivity you can change background for all activities.

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
 @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("Pref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        Boolean isChecked = pref.getBoolean("pref_light", true);
        View rootView = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();

        if (isChecked) {
             rootView.setBackground(bgColor);
        } else {
             rootView.setBackground(bgOtherColor);
        }

    }

}
```

Then instead of doing

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
}
```

do like

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {
}
```

For all the activities